# Casting strings to enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, intellisense, ecmascript-2017

I've ran into a little issue when working with enums in TypeScript. My scenario is this:

- I have defined a string enum containing allowed values
- I have defined a method that accepts any incoming value (of `string` type), and have to cast it to the said enum

The problem is that even after checking if the incoming `value` from the method, intellisense tells me that `value` is still type of `string` instead of the enum. How can I force `value` to be a type of `AllowedValues`?

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```
/** enum */
enum AllowedValues {
    LOREM_IPSUM = 'lorem ipsum',
    DOLOR_SIT = 'dolor sir',
    AMET = 'amet'
}

/** @method */
function doSomething(value: string = AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM) {

    // If value is not found in enum, force it to a default
    if (!(Object as any).values(AllowedValues).includes(value))
        value = AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM;

    // Value should be of type `AllowedValues` here
    // But TypeScript/Intellisense still thinks it is `string`
    console.log(value);
}

doSomething('amet');    // Should log `amet`
doSomething('aloha');   // Should log `lorem ipsum`, since it is not found in `AllowedValues`
```

You can also find it on [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20Color%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Red%2C%20Green%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20To%20String%0D%0A%20var%20green%3A%20string%20%3D%20Color%5BColor.Green%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20To%20Enum%0D%0Avar%20color%20%3A%20Color%20%3D%20Color%5Bgreen%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A).

Comment: const av = Object.keys(AllowedValues).find(k => AllowedValues[k] === 'dolor sir') as AllowedValues;
console.log(av);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.  One is that TypeScript doesn't understand that `Object.values(x).includes(y)` is a [type guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html) on `y`.  It doesn't match the built-in ways that the compiler tries to narrow types, such as `typeof`, `instanceof`, or `in` checks.  To help the compiler out, you can use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to express that way of checking:

```
function isPropertyValue<T>(object: T, possibleValue: any): possibleValue is T[keyof T] {
  return Object.values(object).includes(possibleValue);
}

declare function onlyAcceptAllowedValues(allowedValue: AllowedValues): void;
declare const v: string;
if (isPropertyValue(AllowedValues, v)) {
  onlyAcceptAllowedValues(v); // v is narrowed to AllowedValues; it works!
}
```

So let's first change your function to this:

```
function doSomething(value: string = AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM) {    
  if (!(isPropertyValue(AllowedValues, value)))
    value = AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM;

  // TypeScript/Intellisense still thinks it is `string`
  console.log(value);
}
```

Uh oh, still not working.

---

The second thing going on: if you reassign the value of a variable, TypeScript essentially gives up on its narrowing.  The compiler makes a considerable effort to understand the affect of control flow on variable types, but [it's not perfect](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  So, even though *we* understand that assigning `AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM` to `value` makes it an `AllowedValues`, the compiler [gives up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23044) and assumes that it is its original annotated type, which is `string`.

The way to deal with *this* is to make a new variable which the compiler understands will never be anything but an `AllowedValues`.  The most straightforward way to do that is to make it a `const` variable, like this:

```
function doSomething(value: string = AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM) {    
  const allowedValue = isPropertyValue(AllowedValues, value) ? value : AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM;
  console.log(allowedValue);
}
```

In the above, the new variable `allowedValue` is inferred as an `AllowedValues` because it is set as either `value` if the type guard succeeds (at which point `value` is an `AllowedValues`), or `AllowedValues.LOREM_IPSUM` if the type guard fails.  Either way, `allowedValue` is an `AllowedValues`.

---

So that would be my suggested change if you want to help the compiler understand things. Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer! Now that it makes sense to me: I didn't know that TypeSCript will default to the original annotated type if variable reassignment happens at any point.